# How do I extract a mesh from just one frame of a physics simulation?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

If I simulate 50 boxes falling onto a plane using physics rigid body, how do I get a mesh from just one of those frames? I want all 50 boxes as they have landed, joined together as 1 object that I can use as a single mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

select your objects, then object -> rigid body->"bake to keyframes". Then go to your keyframe, select all objects you want to join and press "ctrl-j".

Comment: Thank you. Have to delete all keyframes from the final object at the end otherwise it will keep animating itself as a giant lump.